# cannot run python/numpy lin-alg from SQL : TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting

Tags: python, sql, numpy

Here is the code i am trying to run from SQL

```
declare @pscript nvarchar(max),@sqlscript nvarchar(max);
set @sqlscript=N'select sku,min_price,med_price,max_price,min_vol,med_vol,max_vol from 
py_alg';
set @pscript=N'
import numpy as np
df1 = InputDataSet
df2 = df1
a = df1["min_price"]
a = np.array(a, dtype = float)
b = df1["med_price"]
b = np.array(b, dtype = float)
c = df1["max_price"]
c = np.array(c, dtype = float)
x = df1["min_vol"]
x = np.array(x, dtype = float)
y = df1["med_vol"]
y = np.array(y, dtype = float)
z = df1["max_vol"]
z = np.array(z, dtype = float)
a1 = [[a * a, a, 1], [b * b, b, 1], [c * c, c, 1]]
b1 = [x, y, z]
result = np.linalg.inv(a1).dot(b1)
df2["a_val"] = result[0]
df2["b_val"] = result[1]
df2["c_val"] = result[2]
OutputDataSet = df2[["sku","a_val","b_val","c_val"]]';
Exec sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = @pscript,
@input_data_1 = @sqlscript

GO
```

this is the error:

```
Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\MSSQL1~1.SQL\MSSQL\EXTENS~1\SQL201701\8EB41034-C5CC-4E7B-83FD-ACD4781832F6\sqlindb.py", line 63, in transform
    result = np.linalg.inv(a1).dot(b1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 526, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc inv
```

Have tried to downgrade numpy to lower version 1.xx.xx as suggested in the forum but could not achieve it.

here is the data table :

```
sku min_price   med_price   max_price   min_vol med_vol max_vol
1   0.99    1.99    2.99    60  51  20
2   300 400 500 2000    1500    1000
3   100 150 200 1000    600 400
4   89  150 210 5000    3000    1500
5   45  60  99  1500    900 700
```

any help pls

I am working on determining the demand curve using quadratic equation, here is the reference on the subject http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-estimating-demand-curves-optimizing-pricing.html

I have written this python code to achieve the same thing & update the a,b,c values in SQL table back, which is working:

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np

connstring = (
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
"Server=[servername];"
"Database=DBM;"
"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

conn = pyodbc.connect(connstring)
conn2 = pyodbc.connect(connstring)


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn2.cursor()

cursor.execute("select 
sku,min_price,med_price,max_price,min_vol,med_vol,max_vol from py_alg")
for row in cursor:

a1 = [[row[1] * row[1], row[1], 1], [row[2] * row[2], row[2], 1], 
[row[3] * row[3], row[3], 1]]
b1 = [row[4], row[5], row[6]]
result = np.linalg.inv(a1).dot(b1)

cursor2.execute("update py_alg set a_val=?, b_val=?, c_val=? where 
sku=?;", (result[0], result[1], result[2],
                                                                              
row[0], ))
conn2.commit()
conn.close()
conn2.close()
```

But wanted to do the same operation by calling from a SQL stored procedure

Comment: Looks like it's having problems with the `a1` variable in `np.linalg.inv(a1)`,  It's a list of lists.  I'm guessing `a`,`b`,`c` are 1d arrays.  Check `np.array(a1)`.  I don't think that will be a 2d (or even 3d) numeric array.

Comment: I have no idea what downgrading numpy is supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

Look at what happens when I try to make part of the `a1` variable from a 5 element `a` array:

```
In [86]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
In [87]: np.array([a*a, a, 1])
<ipython-input-87-335032001ded>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([a*a, a, 1])
Out[87]: 
array([array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 1],
      dtype=object)
```

I suspect you want `a1` to be a (5,3,3) shaped numeric array.

```
a1 = [[a * a, a, 1], [b * b, b, 1], [c * c, c, 1]]
```

won't do that.  It only works if `a`,`b`,`c` are scalars, single  numbers.

If I define:

```
In [88]: ones = np.ones_like(a)
In [89]: ones
Out[89]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

then we can make a numeric array:

```
In [90]: np.array([a*a, a, ones])
Out[90]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

Do that for the whole `a1` expression, and the result will be a (3,3,5) array. It will need a `transpose(2,0,1)` to make a (5,3,3) that `inv` can use.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj for sharing, will try it.  Also have added some more details to my question, pls have a look if it gives more clarity

Comment: I'm not going to help you with SQL part.